# Would days be longer as the polar ice caps melt?

Tags: angular-momentum, geophysics, moment-of-inertia

I got question in my mind striking for several days but not able to prove it, suppose polar ice on earth melt, would the days be longer?
My friend said it was due to moment of inertia of the earth increase but I could not link it up.

Can anyone explain me properly this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the days would be longer.

Since the ice that was at the South Pole is now distributed around the world, there is a change in the distribution of mass. Like an ice skater opening their arms. Since the mass is further from the axis of rotation, the rotation slows; which means the days are longer.